# Localnotification onclick does not work

Tags: angularjs, localnotification, ionic-framework

I'm building a ionic app and use ngcordova localNotification plugin.

I successfully add notification, but when the user clicks over I would remove all notification and go to message page:

```
$scope.addNotification = function (message) {
         $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
             id: '2',
             message:    'Hai ricevuto '+message+' messaggi!',
             title:      'Nuovo messaggi in archivio',  // The title of the message
             }).then(function(){$scope.clickMsg;$state.go('app.messaggi');$scope.cancelAllNotification});
             };

  $scope.clickMsg = function () {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.onclick().then(function () {
        $state.go('app.messaggi');
        console.log('Cambio view');
        $scope.cancelAllNotification
    });
  };
```

but this doesn't work!

Why?